# web.xml error page does not work in case of FileNotFoundException

Tags: jsf, error-handling

I have some problems with customs error pages and their exception type.
I have in my `web.xml` this error page;

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.io.FileNotFoundException</exception-type>
    <location>/faces/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

This error ocurrs when I click in a link and the JSF file does not exist. My problem is when this error happens, the web page does not redirect to my `error.xhtml` page.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: What happens instead then? You forgot to describe the exact use case (how did you try to procude the behaviour?) and the problem symptoms (what exactly happens instead?) which are pretty crucial for identifying the cause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error page on `FileNotFoundException` works only if you were actually requesting an URL which matches the URL pattern of the `FacesServlet`. So imagine that the `FacesServlet` is mapped on `*.jsf`, then opening `/somenotexistent.jsf` will in case of Mojarra indeed throw a subclass of `FileNotFoundException` which would indeed match your error page.

However, if you're requesting an URL which does *not* match the URL pattern of the `FacesServlet`, then the request will be handled by another servlet instead, usually the container's own `DefaultServlet`. If the resource does not exist, then it would usually return a 404 instead of throwing an exception.

You'd like to add another error page to cover that as well:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/faces/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.io.FileNotFoundException</exception-type>
    <location>/faces/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

However, to prevent this duplication, you could also consider to use a [servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) which catches any instance of `FileNotFoundException` coming from `FacesServlet` and then properly returns a 404. JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) has already such a filter, [the `FacesExceptionFilter`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/filters/FacesExceptionFilter). This way you can ultimately end up with only the error page on the error code of 404.

Answer (score 3):

No, as you wrote it the error page is shown when your servlet/JSP/JSF/whatever throws a `FileNotFoundException`. In the case of a 404, your servlet is not even called so it does not throw anything.

Use this

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/the404_page.html</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: Not entirely correct. Mojarra throws a `FacesFileNotFoundException` when a Facelets file is not found when the `FacesServlet` is been requested. This exception is a subclass of `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: Roberto, then you was actually not calling an URL which matches the URL pattern of the `FacesServlet`. Imagine that it is mapped on `*.jsf`, then an attempt to open `/somenotexistent.jsf` would still result in the `FacesFileNotFoundException` instead of 404. If you used `/somewhichdoesnotinvokejsf` then it would not be passed through `FacesServlet` and if it does also not exist, then it would result in a 404.